# Space between tooltip and element MaterializeCSS

Tags: css, materialize

I´m having some issues trying to get the tooltip of an icon closer to it.
This is what I´m trying to do:

[image]

My warning icon looks like this:

```
<i class="material-icons icon-pulse tooltipped" style="color: red; vertical-align: bottom;" data-position="top" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Delayed 17min">report</i>
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `material.js` add a `transform: translateY(10px) translateX(0px)` to the tooltip on hover...Try to change the `translateY` value to reduce the gap.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.material-tooltip {
  transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<i class="material-icons icon-pulse tooltipped" style="color: red; vertical-align: bottom;" data-position="top" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Delayed 17min">report</i>
```

Comment: I have already tried this, but the thing is that It has to be related to its div container, and `top: 20px !important;` is related to the whole webpage. The icon is inside a div, whenever i use that css it does change but relating to the web borders, not the div.

Comment: @Marcelo If that is the issue you can use transform values....try to change the `transformY` value...Updated...!

Comment: Indeed, forgot to thumbs up!